# How to pass more than one values(string,numeric,array etc) to Element Directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive

I will use this directive in another html, and bind these four values(string, int,array etc.) to the directive, but i am unable to get those binding values.
Following is the code, that i have tried for getting.

```
(function () {

"use strict";

angular.module('common').directive('monitoringmenu', ['$rootScope', '$compile',
    function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                entityType: '@',
                entityIds: '@',
                selectedEntityId: '@',
                isOpen: '@'
            },
            link: link,
            templateUrl: './Templates/CommonMenuTemplate.html',
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, el, attrs) {
            $compile(attrs.isOpen);
        }
    }]);
```

})();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically dont need the $compile. 
[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/TDQrBahSyMUPlBkx9E2c?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
})
.directive('monitoringMenu', ['$rootScope', '$compile',
    function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                entityType: '@',
                entityIds: '@',
                selectedEntityId: '@',
                isOpen: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
              console.log(scope);
            },
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
        };
    }]);
```

HTML

```
<monitoring-menu entity-type="asdfg" entity-ids="1" selected-entity-id="1" is-open="true"></monitoring-menu>
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<div>entityType:{{entityType}}</div><br>
<div>entityIds:{{entityIds}}</div><br>
<div>selectedEntityId:{{selectedEntityId}}</div><br>
<div>isOpen:{{isOpen}}</div><br>
```

i put a plunkr to check it out.